# Are the child-friendly trails in the Tatras?

Tags: children, hiking, tatras

Before having kids, we were avid hikers. Our kids are now at an age that we would like to introduce them to this great hobby. Only we don't know where to start, but would like to do so in the Tatras. Are the Tatras at large child unfriendly and if not how do you find a nice starters trail for young children?

Answer (score 8):

Depends on how old the kids are and where exactly you want to go.

I went to the Lower Tatra (somewhere near [Liptovský Mikuláš](https://www.google.co.nz/maps/place/Liptovsk%C3%BD+Mikul%C3%A1%C5%A1/)) with my parents when i was around 10, and we used to go hiking up the mountains or for a half day long walks around the many trails. The trails on to of the mountains at this time where more or less just flat stones placed next to each other, so i had to watch my step, but nothing to hard or to complain about.

Hiking up and down the mountains was a bit an ambitious mission for me even if i was fit and used to long walks, but doable if you take your time, take rest stops or even take the lift up the mountain and walk down. Part of the problem was possible the high altitude which i had to get used to.

Only went to the High Tatra a few days, but from what i remember this is a much more difficult terrain with steeper climbs and more difficult trails.

Remember to take enough food, water and sun blocker with you when you head of. Restaurants, Cafes or Kiosks are pretty rare and the last chance to buy food and drinks is at the bottom or top of the lift stations going up and down the mountains.

So I would answer your question with yes, at least the trails in the Lower Tatra are suitable for children.

Answer (score 2):

I don't how old are your kids, but in polish mountains there are few trails for children:

- Chochołowska Valley (green trail)
- Kościeliska Valley (also green trail)
- Ścieżka pod reglami/Ścieżka nad reglami (I don't how to translate its name to english)
- the path from Palenica glade (Polana Palenica) to Morskie Oko - there are a lot of tourists every year, but you can see many beautiful peaks.
- from Kuźnice (part of Zakopane) to Gąsienicowa Valley (you can choose yeallow trail or blue one)